# Count the number of periods or asterisks in a column

Tags: r, count, character

Basically I have a column called `XX$pitch_by_pitch` that has values such as (F,S,B,X,.,*) etc and I am trying to count how many characters are in this column that are NOT either periods or asterisks.

Sample:

```
pitch=data.frame(c(".CX",".BSCBS",".BSBX",".D",".FFB*B."))
names(pitch)[1]="pitch_by_pitch"
pitch$row=row.names(pitch)
pitch$pitch_by_pitch=as.character(pitch$pitch_by_pitch)
pitch$num=nchar(pitch$pitch_by_pitch)
```

Obviously the last line counts all characters, but I want to remove periods and asterisks.

I have tried things such as:

```
count.slashes <- function(string)sum(unlist(strsplit(string, NULL)) == "*") 
within(x, Col2 <- vapply(Col1, count.slashes, 1)) 
pbp$pitchstar=which(unlist(strsplit(pbp$pitch_by_pitch,NULL)) == '*') 
pbp$pitchstar=str_count(pbp$pitch_by_pitch, "*")
pbp$star=length(which(pbp$pitch_by_pitch == '*'))
```

Comment: A reproducible example would be great.  Why does `length(which(pbp$pitch_by_pitch == '*'))` not work?

Comment: @Amstell What I was missing was the \\ before the astrix and the period. Ugh. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `pitch$num=nchar(gsub("\\*|\\.", "", pitch$pitch_by_pitch))`.

`gsub("\\*|\\.", "", pitch$pitch_by_pitch)` removes all `*` or `.` in the `pitch_by_pitch` column. Afterwards counting the characters using `nchar` should be sufficient:

```
gsub("\\*|\\.", "", pitch$pitch_by_pitch)
# [1] "CX"    "BSCBS" "BSBX"  "D"     "FFBB"
```

Comment: Awesome!! Main issue I think was I was not adding the \\ in front of the * or . and that is why some of the things above were not working. Thanks!!